# How to get values of dynamic textareas in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I am creating text fields inside the `v-for` loop Now confusion is how I can get values of all these inputs those are not fixed number input so I can set their variables in `data()`

How i am rendering inputs

```
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item v-for="(worker, index) in this.workers" :key="index">
          <ion-label text-wrap>
            {{ worker.name }}
          </ion-label>
           <ion-textarea placeholder="Enter Detail..."></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

      <section style="margin: 20px 30px;--color: #272727;"></section>
      <section>
        <ion-button
          shape="round"
          expand="full"
          @click="submit"
          style="--background: #272727;text-transform: capitalize;font-size: 16px;color: #ffc946;"
        >Submit</ion-button>
        <!-- Save -->
      </section>
```

In `submit()` method i want to fetch values of all these textareas

Answer (score 0):

1. In the `template` part you shouldn't use `this`. Actually, Vue should output at least a "warning" for that, if not an "error"
2. Try to think in terms of dataset & -structure. You don't want to "get the data from an input field" - you output an input field based on the data you have. This might sound like a "zen koan", but it's easier to grasp Vue (and other reactive frameworks) with this approach.

Here's a small to show:

```js
Vue.component("InputField", {
  props: ['id', 'value'],
  computed: {
    fieldValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(val) {
        this.$emit("update:value", val)
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
    {{ id }}
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="fieldValue"
    />
    </div>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      formFields: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addField() {
      this.formFields.push({
        id: this.formFields.length + Date.now(),
        value: null,
      })
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
    <button
      @click="addField"
    >
      ADD FIELD +
    </button>
    {{ formFields }}
    <hr />
    <input-field
      v-for="field in formFields"
      :key="field.id"
      :id="field.id"
      :value.sync="field.value"
    />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can get the input value using the v-model directive and debounce this value after 250 milliseconds in the button

```sh
<ion-list>
        <ion-item v-for="(worker, index) in this.workers" :key="index">
          <ion-label text-wrap>
            {{ worker.name }}
          </ion-label>
           <ion-textarea placeholder="Enter Detail..." v-model="input"></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

      <section style="margin: 20px 30px;--color: #272727;"></section>
      <section>
        <ion-button
          shape="round"
          expand="full"
          @click="submit"
          style="--background: #272727;text-transform: capitalize;font-size: 16px;color: #ffc946;"
        >{{buttonText}}</ion-button>
        <!-- Save -->
      </section>
```

Script file/tag:

```sh
export default{
data:{
input: "",
buttonText: "Submit xyz"
},
watch: {
   input: _debounce(function(){
   this.buttonText = this.input !== "" ? "Submit" + this.input : "Submit";
  }, 250)
 },
}
```